# Dynamically sizing 2 dimensional Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on creating the card game "Memory" In WPF. I am having trouble on the UI side of it. I have set it up so  that when the user selects a difficulty it dynamically sets the size of the deck (4x4 for easy, this is what we will be working/talking about for proof of concept). How do I allow for the dynamic change of grid when selecting different difficulties?

This is where you set the difficulty (All the cards are for testing purposes..)

```
 private void SetDifficulty(Difficulty difficulty) {
        //Clearing CardList
        CardList.Clear();
        //Switching on the diff
        switch (difficulty) {
            case Difficulty.Easy:
                CardList = new ObservableCollection<Card>{
                    new Card {
                      Image = Resources.Bowser
                    },
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card(),
                    new Card()
                };

                break;
            case Difficulty.Medium:
                break;
            case Difficulty.Hard:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(difficulty), difficulty, null);
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MemoryGame.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MemoryGame.Views"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MemoryGame.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:MemoryGameViewModel}"
    Title="MainView" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CardList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:Card">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="50" Height="50" >
                    <!--<Image Source="/Pictures/Luigi.jpg"></Image>-->
                    <Button Content="{Binding Image, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50">
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why not initialize them in a for loop?

Comment: it is probably simpler to use UniformGrid, e.g. `<UniformGrid Columns="4" Rows="4"> </UniformGrid>`. Columns and Rows properties support binding, change binding source values and board size will be updated

Comment: I planned on doing that, I added them like that just for testing but the loop would have been even easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer using `ItemsControl` over `ListBox` for the collection in the XAML. I would also BIND the width of the collection and add wrapper panel that allows for wrapping objects:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CardList} Width="{Binding CollWidth}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:Card">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="50" Height="50" >
                <!--<Image Source="/Pictures/Luigi.jpg"></Image>-->
                <Button Content="{Binding Image, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50">
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <!-- A WrapPanel ensures the items wrap to the next line -->
                <!-- when it runs out of room in the collection dimensions -->
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Don't forget to add `CollWidth` property:

```
    private int _collWidth;
    public int CollWidth {
        get { return _collWidth; }
        set {
            _collWidth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CollWidth");
        }
    }
```

Now you can easily modify your `SetDificulty` method:

```
private void SetDifficulty(Difficulty difficulty) {
    // this auto clears everything
    CardList = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
    //Switching on the diff
    switch (difficulty) {
        case Difficulty.Easy:
            // set the width in each level of difficulty to allow wrapper to make nice looking grid
            CollWidth = 200; // (button width is 50) * 4 buttons = 200
            for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
                CardList.Add(new Card()); // or whatever constructor
            break;
        case Difficulty.Medium:
            CollWidth = 250; // (button width is 50) * 5 buttons = 250
            for(int i=0;i<25;i++)
                CardList.Add(new Card()); // or whatever constructor
            break;
        case Difficulty.Hard:
            CollWidth = 300; // (button width is 50) * 6 buttons = 300
            for(int i=0;i<36;i++)
                CardList.Add(new Card()); // or whatever constructor
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(difficulty), difficulty, null);
    }
}
```

You do not have to worry about the `Height` of the collection. The added `<WrapPanel>` will take care of that for you. You only specify the `CollWidth` and the wrap panel will put `CollWidth`/`50` buttons in each row

Comment: Thank you very much. This does EXACTLY what I wanted it to do. I actually ended up throwing an <Image> Tag inside of the button and binding it to the Image property but as for the rest of it.. perfect.

Comment: @ChaseB Glad I could help. If you think it's the answer, I kindly ask you to select it :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `UniformGrid` as ItemsPanel of your ListBox, and bind its `Columns` or `Rows` property to a property in your view model:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CardList}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding GridSize}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Image}" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Content Binding of the Button makes no sense. It only has an effect on Bindings that actually trigger an update of their source property, i.e. TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

It is also bad practice to create UI elements in code behind, like the `Image` property of your `Card` class. Better declare a property of type `ImageSource`, and bind an Image control's `Source` property in XAML:

```
public class Card
{
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
    ...
}

...
var card = new Card
{
    Image = new BitmapeImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Picures/Luigi.jpg"))
};
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Margin="5" Height="50" Width="50">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Yeah, the image was just a hack because I was struggling with trying to get it to show up. Unfortunately this is my first WPF project and don't know all the ins and outs yet. Thank you very much for the tips.